# use inner join where and group by in same query

Tags: sql, database, group-by, inner-join, where-clause

I want select set of data from database to finding sum of column based on other columns value and also want to join two tables and these values are between two dates can i do in single query it please help me to know what i did so far is

```
string sql1 = @"select 
    Ledger.LedId,
    Ledger.LedName,
    sum(adjmnt.OpenBalanceAmount) as Totaldebit, 
    (adjmnt.OpenBalanceVocherType) as adjtype 
from  
    Ledger  inner join Adjustment adjust on
        Ledger.LedId =     adjmnt.LedId 
where  
    Ledger.Date >= @prmStartDate
    and Ledger.Date <= @prmEndDate";
```

what I am looking for to do is

```
string sql1 = @"select
    Ledger.LedId,
    Ledger.LedName,
    sum(adjmnt.OpenBalanceAmount) as Totaldebit , 
    (adjmnt.OpenBalanceVocherType) as adjtype 
from  
    Ledger  inner join Adjustment adjust on 
        Ledger.LedId= adjmnt.LedId 

groupby
    (adjmnt.OpenBalanceVocherType) 

where 
    Ledger.Date >= @prmStartDate and
    Ledger.Date <= @prmEndDate";
```

but when i trying to do this i get

```
incorrect syntax near where
```

please help me

Comment: `where` goes before `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `group by` after `where` and group by `Ledger.LedId,Ledger.LedName` :

```
string sql1 = @"select Ledger.LedId,Ledger.LedName,sum(adjmnt.OpenBalanceAmount) 
Totaldebit ,(adjmnt.OpenBalanceVocherType) as adjtype 
from  Ledger  inner join Adjustment adjmnt on 
Ledger.LedId= adjmnt.LedId
where Ledger.Date >= @prmStartDate and Ledger.Date <= @prmEndDate
group by Ledger.LedId,Ledger.LedName";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1):

I've added a suggestion for formatting to your question.

And when looking at the code in a more structured way, you can instantly tell that there is an error where `groupby` should in fact be `group by`.

And as Mostafa mentioned, the `group by` clause should be placed after the `where` clause.

I don't know if that fixes your problem, but it is surely an error.

Comment: Oh, for some reason the old page got polled for me and the question was unanswered. That's weird... Glad to hear it's fixed!